# How many different numbers can be obtained by arranging the digits contained in the number 1,273,421,695?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

How many different numbers can be obtained by arranging the digits contained in the number $1,273,421,695$? (Commas are not important here)

Part B: How many of these numbers have the digit 6 followed by both 2s?

My approach:

There are two $2$'s, two $1$'s, and one each of $3$,$4$,$5$,$6$,$7$,$9$, so $10$ numbers total.

So there are $10!$ ways to arrange ten numbers, and we have double counted in some of these arrangements since the two $1$'s and two $2$'s are treated as indistinguishable, so the answer should be $\frac{10!}{2!2!} = 907200$. Is it correct?

Part B: strings containing $622$ leave $7$ other numbers with two ones, so $\frac{8!}{2!}=20160$ such numbers.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  More generally, this is known as a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks I updated the question with part b) is it also correct?

Comment: Yes.  Good work.

Comment: Are you sure that “followed by” means “followed immediately by” here?

Comment: @RobPratt that is the intended meaning yes